# Adding Collection Properties to Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to inherit the GridView such that I can add a collection of filter properties which can be shown at design or altered at run time which would be like:-

Is there a way to do this in asp.net 2.0 GridView as I'm getting stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following link:

http://aspalliance.com/946_extended_gridview_control

It has details on how to extend the gridview to add all sort of functionality.